# Excel VBA refer to chart seriescollection by string name

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have a need to refer to a seriescollection by name. The MSDN object model page for seriescollection states either an index or a name can be used. However when I try to use a string variable I get error 1004 'Invalid parameter':

```
Dim sSeriesName As String
dim aRootCats() as string
Dim cSeriesCol As SeriesCollection

For x = 0 To UBound(aRootCats)
    sSeriesName = aRootCats(x)
    Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(sSeriesName)
Next x
```

I've tried the following too:

```
    sSeriesName = CStr(aRootCats(x)) ' just in case, because I filled this array with variant data type earlier
    Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(sSeriesName)
```

and

```
    Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(aRootCats(x))
```

and

```
    Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection("Product Support")
```

UPDATE: I'm also experiencing the same error when looping on the seriescollection:

```
For c = 1 To cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection.Count
    Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(c)
Next c
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Generally you'd get that error if the series name doesn't match.

Comment: Thanks but it definitely does, in debugging I got the exact names with cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(1).name etc

Comment: So testing something like `aRootCats(x) = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(1).name` returns True?

Comment: Yes, I get a true / false as appropriate. I'm thinking of doing this with another loop inside the first, this time on the series collection - is that your thought too?

Comment: Not really, since I can't replicate your error other than when the series name is incorrect. Can you put a file somewhere (OneDrive / Dropbox etc) showing the problem? If it's a bug, I'll report it. Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Thanks Rory but I can't, it's commercially sensitive. Stumped...I tried the loop and got the same error:
    
    For c = 1 To cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection.Count
        If aRootCats(x) = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(c).Name Then
            Set cSeriesCol = cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection(c)
            cSeriesCol.PlotOrder = x + 1
        End If
    Next c

Comment: Ah - I didn't see that you were using a ChartGroup not a Chart. Use: `cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection.Item(sSeriesName)` instead.

Comment: Thank you - I get a type mismatch using sSeriesname but works OK using an index number so the inner loop idea will now work. Still puzzled as to why a string doesn't work but please post an answer if you'd like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a ChartGroup not a Chart, you have to use the `Item` property of the `SeriesCollection` and you have to pass a variant. Use either:

```
cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection.Item(1)
```

or:

```
cChart.ChartGroups(1).SeriesCollection.Item(CVar(sSeriesName))
```

(or declare the variable as Variant rather than String)

Comment: Yes, declaring as variant works. Thanks for all your help.